# How to change color of an anchor on hover over a dropdown

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I am trying to change color of the text on hover from black to white but even though i have given the property as white it's not reflecting .Is there anything  I am missing?

Comment: try using `color: #ffffff !important;`

Comment: Can you give working example in fiddle or code pen?

Comment: @mrid tried didn't change .thanks anyways

Comment: Is there any `span` element inside the anchor tag??

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt yes it's there

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt <span class="text">Monday</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>

Comment: @saurabhkumar See the answer below. It will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the color of `span` tag on `a` tag hover. Try below code

```
#bidashboard .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover span.text{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

It will work.

Comment: @saurabhkumar  could you provide an another screenshot with span tag selected in console?

Comment: i just had to remove span's color property ,thanks a lot Bhuvan

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, we see that there are still elements in the `a` tag. Their styles are more priority. Use `color: #ffffff` to someting that  inside this tag. 
In general use `color: #ffffff !important;` or  make the weight of selectors larger.

Comment: _or make the weight of selectors larger._ what does that mean?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt
example: `.selector a{color:red}` will block `a{color:black}`
I said about those regulations.

Comment: @saurabhkumar 
The first part of my answer  said that you should do. You must using css to something in your `a`